# Display images with bounding boxes while running py-faster-rcnn using VGG_CNN_M_1024

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am using the `demo.py`given in https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/tree/master/tools.

I have modified the code to run `VGG_CNN_M_1024` as I am using a 2GB GPU. And as per the comments given in https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/issues/2, I chose to run `VGG_CNN_M_1024.caffemodel` instead of `VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel`

This is the code in `demo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# --------------------------------------------------------
# Faster R-CNN
# Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft
# Licensed under The MIT License [see LICENSE for details]
# Written by Ross Girshick
# --------------------------------------------------------

"""
Demo script showing detections in sample images.

See README.md for installation instructions before running.
"""

import _init_paths
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
from fast_rcnn.test import im_detect
from fast_rcnn.nms_wrapper import nms
from utils.timer import Timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import caffe, os, sys, cv2
import argparse

CLASSES = ('__background__',
           'aeroplane', 'bicycle', 'bird', 'boat',
           'bottle', 'bus', 'car', 'cat', 'chair',
           'cow', 'diningtable', 'dog', 'horse',
           'motorbike', 'person', 'pottedplant',
           'sheep', 'sofa', 'train', 'tvmonitor')

NETS = {'vgg16': ('VGG16',
                  'VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel'),
        'zf': ('ZF',
                  'ZF_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel'),
         'vgg16_m_1024':('VGG_CNN_M_1024','VGG_CNN_M_1024.caffemodel')}


def vis_detections(im, class_name, dets, thresh=0.5):
    """Draw detected bounding boxes."""
    inds = np.where(dets[:, -1] >= thresh)[0]
    if len(inds) == 0:
        return

    im = im[:, :, (2, 1, 0)]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax.imshow(im, aspect='equal')
    for i in inds:
        bbox = dets[i, :4]
        score = dets[i, -1]

        ax.add_patch(
            plt.Rectangle((bbox[0], bbox[1]),
                          bbox[2] - bbox[0],
                          bbox[3] - bbox[1], fill=False,
                          edgecolor='red', linewidth=3.5)
            )
        ax.text(bbox[0], bbox[1] - 2,
                '{:s} {:.3f}'.format(class_name, score),
                bbox=dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5),
                fontsize=14, color='white')

    ax.set_title(('{} detections with '
                  'p({} | box) >= {:.1f}').format(class_name, class_name,
                                                  thresh),
                  fontsize=14)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.draw()

def demo(net, image_name):
    """Detect object classes in an image using pre-computed object proposals."""

    # Load the demo image
    im_file = os.path.join(cfg.DATA_DIR, 'demo', image_name)
    im = cv2.imread(im_file)

    # Detect all object classes and regress object bounds
    timer = Timer()
    timer.tic()
    scores, boxes = im_detect(net, im)
    timer.toc()
    print ('Detection took {:.3f}s for '
           '{:d} object proposals').format(timer.total_time, boxes.shape[0])

    # Visualize detections for each class
    CONF_THRESH = 0.8
    NMS_THRESH = 0.3
    for cls_ind, cls in enumerate(CLASSES[1:]):
        cls_ind += 1 # because we skipped background
        cls_boxes = boxes[:, 4*cls_ind:4*(cls_ind + 1)]
        cls_scores = scores[:, cls_ind]
        dets = np.hstack((cls_boxes,
                          cls_scores[:, np.newaxis])).astype(np.float32)
        keep = nms(dets, NMS_THRESH)
        dets = dets[keep, :]
        vis_detections(im, cls, dets, thresh=CONF_THRESH)

def parse_args():
    """Parse input arguments."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Faster R-CNN demo')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu', dest='gpu_id', help='GPU device id to use [0]',
                        default=0, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--cpu', dest='cpu_mode',
                        help='Use CPU mode (overrides --gpu)',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--net', dest='demo_net', help='Network to use [vgg16]',
                        choices=NETS.keys(), default='vgg16_m_1024')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg.TEST.HAS_RPN = True  # Use RPN for proposals

    args = parse_args()

    prototxt = os.path.join(cfg.MODELS_DIR, NETS[args.demo_net][0],
                            'faster_rcnn_alt_opt', 'faster_rcnn_test.pt')
    caffemodel = os.path.join(cfg.DATA_DIR, 'faster_rcnn_models',
                              NETS[args.demo_net][1])

    if not os.path.isfile(caffemodel):
        raise IOError(('{:s} not found.\nDid you run ./data/script/'
                       'fetch_faster_rcnn_models.sh?').format(caffemodel))

    if args.cpu_mode:
        caffe.set_mode_cpu()
    else:
        caffe.set_mode_gpu()
        caffe.set_device(args.gpu_id)
        cfg.GPU_ID = args.gpu_id
    net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TEST)

    print '\n\nLoaded network {:s}'.format(caffemodel)

    # Warmup on a dummy image
    im = 128 * np.ones((300, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in xrange(2):
        _, _= im_detect(net, im)

    im_names = ['000456.jpg', '000542.jpg', '001150.jpg',
                '001763.jpg', '004545.jpg']
    for im_name in im_names:
        print '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
        print 'Demo for data/demo/{}'.format(im_name)
        demo(net, im_name)

    plt.show()
```

And this is `config.py`

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Fast R-CNN
# Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft
# Licensed under The MIT License [see LICENSE for details]
# Written by Ross Girshick
# --------------------------------------------------------

"""Fast R-CNN config system.

This file specifies default config options for Fast R-CNN. You should not
change values in this file. Instead, you should write a config file (in yaml)
and use cfg_from_file(yaml_file) to load it and override the default options.

Most tools in $ROOT/tools take a --cfg option to specify an override file.
    - See tools/{train,test}_net.py for example code that uses cfg_from_file()
    - See experiments/cfgs/*.yml for example YAML config override files
"""

import os
import os.path as osp
import numpy as np
# `pip install easydict` if you don't have it
from easydict import EasyDict as edict

__C = edict()
# Consumers can get config by:
#   from fast_rcnn_config import cfg
cfg = __C

#
# Training options
#

__C.TRAIN = edict()

# Scales to use during training (can list multiple scales)
# Each scale is the pixel size of an image's shortest side
__C.TRAIN.SCALES = (600,)

# Max pixel size of the longest side of a scaled input image
__C.TRAIN.MAX_SIZE = 1000

# Images to use per minibatch
__C.TRAIN.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2

# Minibatch size (number of regions of interest [ROIs])
__C.TRAIN.BATCH_SIZE = 128

# Fraction of minibatch that is labeled foreground (i.e. class > 0)
__C.TRAIN.FG_FRACTION = 0.25

# Overlap threshold for a ROI to be considered foreground (if >= FG_THRESH)
__C.TRAIN.FG_THRESH = 0.5

# Overlap threshold for a ROI to be considered background (class = 0 if
# overlap in [LO, HI))
__C.TRAIN.BG_THRESH_HI = 0.5
__C.TRAIN.BG_THRESH_LO = 0.1

# Use horizontally-flipped images during training?
__C.TRAIN.USE_FLIPPED = True

# Train bounding-box regressors
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_REG = True

# Overlap required between a ROI and ground-truth box in order for that ROI to
# be used as a bounding-box regression training example
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_THRESH = 0.5

# Iterations between snapshots
__C.TRAIN.SNAPSHOT_ITERS = 10000

# solver.prototxt specifies the snapshot path prefix, this adds an optional
# infix to yield the path: <prefix>[_<infix>]_iters_XYZ.caffemodel
__C.TRAIN.SNAPSHOT_INFIX = ''

# Use a prefetch thread in roi_data_layer.layer
# So far I haven't found this useful; likely more engineering work is required
__C.TRAIN.USE_PREFETCH = False

# Normalize the targets (subtract empirical mean, divide by empirical stddev)
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS = True
# Deprecated (inside weights)
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_INSIDE_WEIGHTS = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
# Normalize the targets using "precomputed" (or made up) means and stdevs
# (BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS must also be True)
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED = False
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_NORMALIZE_MEANS = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
__C.TRAIN.BBOX_NORMALIZE_STDS = (0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2)

# Train using these proposals
__C.TRAIN.PROPOSAL_METHOD = 'selective_search'

# Make minibatches from images that have similar aspect ratios (i.e. both
# tall and thin or both short and wide) in order to avoid wasting computation
# on zero-padding.
__C.TRAIN.ASPECT_GROUPING = True

# Use RPN to detect objects
__C.TRAIN.HAS_RPN = False
# IOU >= thresh: positive example
__C.TRAIN.RPN_POSITIVE_OVERLAP = 0.7
# IOU < thresh: negative example
__C.TRAIN.RPN_NEGATIVE_OVERLAP = 0.3
# If an anchor statisfied by positive and negative conditions set to negative
__C.TRAIN.RPN_CLOBBER_POSITIVES = False
# Max number of foreground examples
__C.TRAIN.RPN_FG_FRACTION = 0.5
# Total number of examples
__C.TRAIN.RPN_BATCHSIZE = 256
# NMS threshold used on RPN proposals
__C.TRAIN.RPN_NMS_THRESH = 0.7
# Number of top scoring boxes to keep before apply NMS to RPN proposals
__C.TRAIN.RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N = 12000
# Number of top scoring boxes to keep after applying NMS to RPN proposals
__C.TRAIN.RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N = 2000
# Proposal height and width both need to be greater than RPN_MIN_SIZE (at orig image scale)
__C.TRAIN.RPN_MIN_SIZE = 16
# Deprecated (outside weights)
__C.TRAIN.RPN_BBOX_INSIDE_WEIGHTS = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
# Give the positive RPN examples weight of p * 1 / {num positives}
# and give negatives a weight of (1 - p)
# Set to -1.0 to use uniform example weighting
__C.TRAIN.RPN_POSITIVE_WEIGHT = -1.0


#
# Testing options
#

__C.TEST = edict()

# Scales to use during testing (can list multiple scales)
# Each scale is the pixel size of an image's shortest side
__C.TEST.SCALES = (600,)

# Max pixel size of the longest side of a scaled input image
__C.TEST.MAX_SIZE = 1000

# Overlap threshold used for non-maximum suppression (suppress boxes with
# IoU >= this threshold)
__C.TEST.NMS = 0.3

# Experimental: treat the (K+1) units in the cls_score layer as linear
# predictors (trained, eg, with one-vs-rest SVMs).
__C.TEST.SVM = False

# Test using bounding-box regressors
__C.TEST.BBOX_REG = True

# Propose boxes
__C.TEST.HAS_RPN = False

# Test using these proposals
__C.TEST.PROPOSAL_METHOD = 'selective_search'

## NMS threshold used on RPN proposals
__C.TEST.RPN_NMS_THRESH = 0.7
## Number of top scoring boxes to keep before apply NMS to RPN proposals
__C.TEST.RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N = 6000
## Number of top scoring boxes to keep after applying NMS to RPN proposals
__C.TEST.RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N = 300
# Proposal height and width both need to be greater than RPN_MIN_SIZE (at orig image scale)
__C.TEST.RPN_MIN_SIZE = 16


#
# MISC
#

# The mapping from image coordinates to feature map coordinates might cause
# some boxes that are distinct in image space to become identical in feature
# coordinates. If DEDUP_BOXES > 0, then DEDUP_BOXES is used as the scale factor
# for identifying duplicate boxes.
# 1/16 is correct for {Alex,Caffe}Net, VGG_CNN_M_1024, and VGG16
__C.DEDUP_BOXES = 1./16.

# Pixel mean values (BGR order) as a (1, 1, 3) array
# We use the same pixel mean for all networks even though it's not exactly what
# they were trained with
__C.PIXEL_MEANS = np.array([[[102.9801, 115.9465, 122.7717]]])

# For reproducibility
__C.RNG_SEED = 3

# A small number that's used many times
__C.EPS = 1e-14

# Root directory of project
__C.ROOT_DIR = osp.abspath(osp.join(osp.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))

# Data directory
__C.DATA_DIR = osp.abspath(osp.join(__C.ROOT_DIR, 'data'))

# Model directory
__C.MODELS_DIR = osp.abspath(osp.join(__C.ROOT_DIR, 'models', 'pascal_voc'))

# Name (or path to) the matlab executable
__C.MATLAB = 'matlab'

# Place outputs under an experiments directory
__C.EXP_DIR = 'default'

# Use GPU implementation of non-maximum suppression
__C.USE_GPU_NMS = False

# Default GPU device id
__C.GPU_ID = 0


def get_output_dir(imdb, net=None):
    """Return the directory where experimental artifacts are placed.
    If the directory does not exist, it is created.

    A canonical path is built using the name from an imdb and a network
    (if not None).
    """
    outdir = osp.abspath(osp.join(__C.ROOT_DIR, 'output', __C.EXP_DIR, imdb.name))
    if net is not None:
        outdir = osp.join(outdir, net.name)
    if not os.path.exists(outdir):
        os.makedirs(outdir)
    return outdir

def _merge_a_into_b(a, b):
    """Merge config dictionary a into config dictionary b, clobbering the
    options in b whenever they are also specified in a.
    """
    if type(a) is not edict:
        return

    for k, v in a.iteritems():
        # a must specify keys that are in b
        if not b.has_key(k):
            raise KeyError('{} is not a valid config key'.format(k))

        # the types must match, too
        old_type = type(b[k])
        if old_type is not type(v):
            if isinstance(b[k], np.ndarray):
                v = np.array(v, dtype=b[k].dtype)
            else:
                raise ValueError(('Type mismatch ({} vs. {}) '
                                'for config key: {}').format(type(b[k]),
                                                            type(v), k))

        # recursively merge dicts
        if type(v) is edict:
            try:
                _merge_a_into_b(a[k], b[k])
            except:
                print('Error under config key: {}'.format(k))
                raise
        else:
            b[k] = v

def cfg_from_file(filename):
    """Load a config file and merge it into the default options."""
    import yaml
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        yaml_cfg = edict(yaml.load(f))

    _merge_a_into_b(yaml_cfg, __C)

def cfg_from_list(cfg_list):
    """Set config keys via list (e.g., from command line)."""
    from ast import literal_eval
    assert len(cfg_list) % 2 == 0
    for k, v in zip(cfg_list[0::2], cfg_list[1::2]):
        key_list = k.split('.')
        d = __C
        for subkey in key_list[:-1]:
            assert d.has_key(subkey)
            d = d[subkey]
        subkey = key_list[-1]
        assert d.has_key(subkey)
        try:
            value = literal_eval(v)
        except:
            # handle the case when v is a string literal
            value = v
        assert type(value) == type(d[subkey]), \
            'type {} does not match original type {}'.format(
            type(value), type(d[subkey]))
        d[subkey] = value
```

Whenever I run the code with a ZF net, I get the output images with the bounding box.

The terminal output is given here for ZF : http://txt.do/5bqsf

However, when I run the code with the VGG_CNN_M_1024 net, there isn't any output images displayed, even though the code runs successfully.

The terminal output is given here for VGG_CNN_M_1024 : http://txt.do/5bqsf

What do I change in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel is the model learned via Faster RCNN.
This model would have been initialised using VGG16.caffemodel.

What you're after is a faster rcnn model, which has been initialised using the VGG_CNN_M_1024.caffemodel. Such a model would be called 
VGG_CNN_M_1024_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel if it followed the above naming convention.

If the model is not available online, you'll need to train it on the PASCAL dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As u had mentioned your not able to use the model , one alternative you can do is place ur trained model in the faster_rccn_models folder just change 
 VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel to the following 
VGG_CNN_M_1024.caffemodel instead of adding a third one in the net, i follow the same convention and it works for me always